# Environment effect on slew rate of operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, slew-rate

Is there any environmental condition that will affect the slew rate of operational amplifier? I have been searching on it but there is no solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the internal capacitor is implemented, temperature and VDD can seriously affect the capacitor value.

And if the opamp's internal bias generator is improperly implemented (or tradeoffs were
made to favor other performance issues than constant SlewRate), the charging current may vary.